# How to mock Facebook login using react-native Detox?

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

A common issue on the Detox repo is how to login to Facebook in tests (https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/287).

Answer: “mock the FB API to return a valid session without the actual login process.”

Sure! Sounds like a great idea, but… how? Can someone point me in the right direction?

The Detox docks mentions *react-native-repackager* (https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md) to one could use `SomeFile.e2e.js` instead of `SomeFile.js` but I’m clueless how to mock a lib in `node_modules/` (*react-native-fbsdk* in this case).

Comment: Why not just mock your own code, instead of the fbsdk one? Just mock the parts of your code where you call some fbsdk methods.

Comment: Why, yes, ofc. I'm a slow thinker it seems. Thank you!